# Respond with latex code to web request with django

Tags: django, latex, django-templates

I am new to python for web apps, and am using django for my first try. Since the app should create some latex files dynamically, I thought that the most elegant way would be to return the latex file as a web request and create the contents dynamically using the django template engine. However, the template syntax consists of characters ({, % and }) that are special characters in latex, too. So in this special case, I would want to change the syntax of the django template system.

My questions are:

1. Do you think this is the recommended way to do latex file creation? Or should I open the template files using python and just create regexps for all the variables and so on. (I would *really* prefer the django template way!)
2. How can I change the way variables and functions are substituted in django templates? E.g. {{ x }} to << x >> or anything like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, the Django template language doesn't allow for custom syntaxes. Fortunately, there's another pluggable templating system called [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) that does.

See this [blog post](http://e6h.de/post/11/) for someone else's experience with LaTeX and Jinja2.

[Official Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment) on the subject.

Comment: Very neat! Especially since I don't have to change existing templates!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jinja2, or maybe you can do that by using the default template system too:

Looking at the code for `django/template/__init__.py`, Around line `78` (Django 1.2) I saw this:

```
75 # template syntax constants
76 FILTER_SEPARATOR = '|'
77 FILTER_ARGUMENT_SEPARATOR = ':'
78 VARIABLE_ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR = '.'
79 BLOCK_TAG_START = '{%'
80 BLOCK_TAG_END = '%}'
81 VARIABLE_TAG_START = '{{'
82 VARIABLE_TAG_END = '}}'
83 COMMENT_TAG_START = '{#'
84 COMMENT_TAG_END = '#}'
85 SINGLE_BRACE_START = '{'
86 SINGLE_BRACE_END = '}'
```

So, there's a chance that you can manage to replace that constants (for just a limited usage) with some custom ones..

Don't monkeypatch directly, as changing that constants in that module would prevent default views from being rendered correctly.

Comment: Ok, as far as I saw from the code I think to do that you have to copy the whole code of `django.template` package somewhere inside your application, rename it to something like `template2` and change template syntax constants as you like; then make use of functions from `template2` for the latex file rendering only.. ..or just use Jinja :)